# Javascript String.prototype.replaceAll function does not exist according to Node v14.16.0

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following code in which I try to reduce all instances of more than one whitespace to just one whitespace:

```
let string = 'X    X    X    X    X';
string = string.replaceAll(/\s+/, ' ');
```

This is giving me an error `TypeError: string.replaceAll is not a function`, while the function exists according to the MDN website! Anyone has a clue what is going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need Node 15+ to use `replaceAll`.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#browser_compatibility

Comment: You can use `string.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');` pretty much anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. What is the added 'g' saying exactly? I am terrible with regex :(

Comment: It's the "global" flag. You should not use it all the time, but in this case it's exactly what you want.

Comment: ...and replaceAll method with a regex should be with a global flag